# Changing Excel Sheet every time python script runs

Tags: python, xlwt

I need to change the sheet in an excel workbook, as many times as the code runs..Suppose my python scripts runs the first time and data gets saved in sheet A, next time when some application runs my script data should be saved in sheet B.Sheet A should be as it is in that workbook..
Is it posible ? If yes ,How?
Here is my code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import subprocess
import xlwt
process=subprocess.Popen('Test_Project.exe',stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
out,err = process.communicate()
wb=xlwt.Workbook()
sheet=wb.add_sheet('Sheet_A') #next time it should save in Sheet_B
row = 0
for line in out.split('\n'): 
    for i,wrd in enumerate(line.split()):    
        if not wrd.startswith("***"):
            print wrd   
        sheet.write(row,i,wrd)
    row=row+1

wb.save('DDS.xls')
```

Any help is appreciated...

Comment: This seems to be fairly simple logic: find the last non-empty worksheet and use the next one. What are you having trouble with?

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong: you want to prepend the data into another sheet of an existing workbook several times?

Comment: @alecxe I dont want to prepend the data.Its just that I have to read an application and store its data into an excel sheet.Then, when the application has got a different data ,I have to read it again and store into another sheet, so that I can compare both sheets later.

Comment: Yes, the key point is that it's the same workbook. In that case, the answer is: you cannot edit an existing workbook with xlwt. First, you should open it via xlrd, read the existing data, rewrite it and add another data portion to the different sheet using xlwt.

Comment: If I'm still correctly understand the problem, there are several options: use different workbooks for every new portion of data (instead of sheets) or collect the data somewhere in the database and write it to the excel sheet before comparing.

Comment: I am new to python .And from all the reading ,that is what I also understood..Without using xlrd , its not possible.However I was wondering how can we use different workbook each time.Because we need to save it using a name.I cant edit my script every time it runs.rit?

Comment: If it is ok for you to make a new workbook each time you need to put data into an excel file, you can make a directory with the required name and save excel files with different names (like `1.xls`, `2.xls`, or using timestamps).

Comment: This is not the requirement here..This scripts needs to run continuosly for an application.Its Test_Project.exe which will change time to time.So script cant be edited once we run it everytime for new Test_Projec.exe...I wil use the xlrd instead...Anyways thanks a lot alecxe.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using [openpyxl](http://pythonhosted.org/openpyxl/). It can read **and** write xlsx files.
If needed, you can always convert them to xls with Excel or Open/LibreOffice,
assuming you have only one big file at the end.

This script creates a new Excel file if none exists and adds a new sheet every time it is run. I use the `index + 1` as the sheet name (`title`) starting with 1. The numerical index starts at 0. You will end up with a file that has sheets named `1`, `2`, `3` etc. Every time you write your data into the last sheet.

```
import os

from openpyxl import Workbook
from openpyxl.reader.excel import load_workbook

file_name = 'test.xlsx'

if os.path.exists(file_name):
    wb = load_workbook(file_name)
    last_sheet = wb.worksheets[-1]
    index = int(last_sheet.title)
    ws = wb.create_sheet(index)
    ws.title = str(index + 1)
else:
    wb = Workbook()
    ws = wb.worksheets[0]
    ws.title = '1'
ws.cell('A2').value= 'new_value'
wb.save(file_name)
```

Comment: @Pragya Any success with this solution?